# Was there an X-Men comic where somebody kept calling Magneto "Magento"?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics, x-men

I have a vague recollection of an X-Men comic book in which another villain has allied with Magneto, but he (intentionally or not--I don't remember, and it may not have been clear in the comic) keeps calling Magneto "Magento" or "Magenta," apparently in reference to his red costume.  This probably would have been a comic book from the early 1970s, since most of the comic books I read as a kid came from my uncle's collection, which was of that vintage.  However, it could have been later, possibly as late as the early 1990s.

When was this, and who was the other villain?

Comment: Sounds like Arcade's attitude to other villains.

Comment: Are you possibly thinking of DC's [Magenta](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/magenta/4005-10461/), another character with magnetic powers?  Her first appearance was in [*The New Teen Titans* #17](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/the-new-teen-titans-17-the-possessing-of-francis-k/4000-21986/) (March 1982).

Comment: @Gaultheria I don't think so, no.

Comment: Does this image ring any bells? https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e1/40/a2/e140a2ccfdba6b9f53abcd44d6f9e572.jpg